# Qt QGraphicsEllipseItem subclass doesn't display

Tags: c++, qt, class

I'm trying to create a subclass of `QGraphicsEllipseItem` so I can add some functionality.  However, in even a very basic test, the subclass object does not display in the scene.  In the following code, only the blue circle at `(-30,0)` displays, but not the red circle at `(30,0)`.  What am I doing wrong?

In researching the problem, I saw that paint is commonly overridden for `QGraphicsItem` subclasses, so I tried that, only calling `QGraphicsEllipseItem::paint` in the `myEllipseItem::paint`, but that made no difference.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**widget.h**

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsItem>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();
private:
    QGraphicsScene* scene;
};

class myEllipseItem : public QGraphicsEllipseItem
{
public:
    myEllipseItem(float a, float b, float c, float d) {QGraphicsEllipseItem(a,b,c,d);}
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

**widget.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"

#include <QLayout>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    scene = new QGraphicsScene();

    QGraphicsEllipseItem* qIcon = new QGraphicsEllipseItem(0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 20.0);
    qIcon->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::blue));
    scene->addItem(qIcon);
    qIcon->setPos(-30,0);

    myEllipseItem* myIcon = new myEllipseItem(0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 20.0);
    myIcon->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::red));
    scene->addItem(myIcon);
    myIcon->setPos(30,0);

    QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView();
    view->setScene(scene);
    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;
    layout->addWidget(view);
    setLayout(layout);

}

Widget::~Widget()
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor is not correct. You should use next (in my example it has empty body but you can do all needed things):

header:

```
#ifndef MYELLIPSEITEM_H
#define MYELLIPSEITEM_H

#include <QGraphicsEllipseItem>

class myEllipseItem : public QGraphicsEllipseItem
{
public:
    myEllipseItem(float a, float b, float c, float d): QGraphicsEllipseItem(a,b,c,d){}
};

#endif // MYCOLORDIALOG_H
```

And as you can see, I used separate header file. Another example how to use body of constructor:

```
myEllipseItem(float a, float b, float c, float d): QGraphicsEllipseItem(a,b,c,d)
{
    this->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::green));
}
```

Now ellipse has "default" color - green.

Comment: Hah, that did it!  I didn't realize the parent constructor was required to be called from the initialization list, thanks!